# 3 divs in a container div, make one of them expand if another is cancelled out

Tags: css

I have 3 divs in a parent div which looks like this:

```
<div id="maincontent>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="mainbody"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

The website is 1000px wide.

What I need is to keep the `.mainbody` div at a minimum of 570px, but have it expand if one of the other 2 divs is removed from the page, which are each given 215px width.

All 3 divs are also floated left.

I tried using `min-width` and `max-width` on `.mainbody` but it doesn't really work. Any other ideas?

My current CSS:

```
#maincontent {

  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left, .right, .mainbody {

  float: left;
}

.left, .right {

  width: 215px;
}

.mainbody {

  width: 570px;
}
```

Comment: What does cancelled out mean?

Comment: And how does one "delete" a div?

Comment: What does it matter? It's a CMS in question.

Comment: Ok then. Best of luck.

Comment: Use a **table**. This way, if you delete a table-cell, the others are gonna take all available space.

Comment: Table is not an option

Comment: You've tagged question with CSS, but I think that can be done with jQuery.

Comment: what about inserting you .right inside the .mainbody ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ad and event to the function. `.click(), .ready()` etc

```
if($('.right').is(':visible') == false){ 
   $('.mainbody').width(785+'px'); 
}
else{ }
```

or use `.size() / .length()`

Comment: The div is there, but it's empty (I am using a CMS). How would this code be tweaked so it checks if the div is empty?

Comment: I belive the OP is not asking for a JS solution as there is no JS tag on the OP.

Comment: I was hoping to do it with CSS, but if JS is the only solution what to do.

Comment: Miljan, thanks. With your help and then the code from Axente it works now.

Answer (score 2):

### CSS Only Solution 1

**This assumes the question was accurate in stating "if one of the other 2 divs is removed from the page."**

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yKGzr/4/) which uses the following code, the key part of which is the `:first-child` and `:last-child` change based off your html structure change that you mention. When the `left` is deleted, the `mainbody` becomes the `first-child` and when the `right` is deleted the `mainbody` becomes the `last-child`, so you reset the `width` if such occurs.

**Key CSS**

```
.mainbody {
    width: 570px;
    float: left;
}

.mainbody:first-child,
.mainbody:last-child {
    width: 785px;
}

.left,
.right {
    width: 215px;
    float: left;
}
```

### CSS Only Solution 2

**This accounts for the `div` remaining, but having no content and being zero width (which is apparently what the situation actually is).**

There is a CSS only solution ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yKGzr/6/)), but it requires one to restructure the HTML order of the elements and to adjust how they are floated.

**Needed HTML Structure (`mainbody` is last)**

```
<div id="maincontent1">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="mainbody"></div>
</div>
```

**Key CSS**

```
.mainbody {
    min-width: 570px;
    overflow: hidden; /* this triggers expansion between left/right */
}

.left {
    width: 215px; /* this is assumed to be zero if no content in div */
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 215px; /* this is assumed to be zero if no content in div */
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: She doesn't really remove those `div`s, just removes their content. But really nice solution!

Comment: The question says "if one of the other 2 divs is removed from the page," which is a removal of the `div`. If it is merely content being removed, then the question should be restated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am using a CMS and I thought the div wouldn't be there with no content, but it was there either way as it turned out. I didn't try this as it's much simpler with Jquery, but vote up.

Comment: @OliveraKovacevic: No problem. I did add a second css only solution that deals with zero width `left` or `right` div's, but it would require a restructure of the html and a reconfiguration of how the elements are floated. I don't know if that is a viable option for you, but I offered it for future seekers.